# JSP : How to link form select option to Java object

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I have two objects which are linked. `Address` which has a `Country` with a `ManyToOne` relationship linked by `countryId`. I am trying to add a webpage using JSP to add a new `Address`. On this page you are able to select a `Country` from a dropdown.

I have tried a number of different ways to do this but i cannot seem to link the `Country` object in the dropdown to the `Country` object in the `Address`, i keep getting the following error

```
Field error in object 'address' on field 'country': rejected value [com.company.project.domain.Country@670b11d7]; codes [typeMismatch.address.country,typeMismatch.country,typeMismatch.com.company.project.domain.Country,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [address.country,country]; arguments []; default message [country]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.company.project.domain.Country' for property 'country'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.company.project.domain.Country] for property 'country': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

These are two of many different options i have tried but i keep getting the same error

***Try 1***
**JAVA**

```
List<Country> countries = countryService.getAllCountrys();
    LinkedHashMap<Country, String> countryMap = new LinkedHashMap<Country, String>();
    for(Country country : countries){
        countryMap.put(country, country.getCountryName());
    }

    model.addAttribute("countries", countryMap);
```

***Try 1***
**JSP**

```
<tr>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td><form:select path="country">
    <form:options items="${countries}" />
    </form:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

***Try 2***
**JAVA**

```
List<Country> countries= countryService.getAllCountry();
    model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
```

***Try 2***
**JSP**

```
<tr>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td><form:select path="country" id="country">
        <form:options items="${countries}" itemValue="country" itemLabel="countryName" />
    </form:select>
</tr>
```

I can get the dropdowns populating correctly but wen i try to save it is seems to be trying to save a string value rather then the object value. I am using a POST request to save the page

Does anyone know how  to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for these case it's how I do  :

JAVA

```
List<Country> countries= countryService.getAllCountry();
model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
```

JSP

```
<select name="idCountry">   
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
<option value="${country.id}">${contry.countryName}</option> 
</c:forEach>
```

POST JAVA

```
Country c = CountryRepositroy.findById();
Adresse.setCountry(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the object value , as HTML form submits the String value that is assigned to the drop down by itemValue attribute of form:options.
One thing you try is take id as value of the country and create country object from it and then try to save that.

Also your submitting the Country object as whole, I would suggest you to just get the id as value and name as value to be displayed in drop down and at server side create the country object from id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your collection to request. See exapmple below

```
    request.setAttribute("countries", countryMap);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```